# How to use file *.acv to video in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have an application Andoroid . I want to see more effects to video using photoshop file and preview it .acv . I have problems with the preview . Who has the solution to the problem by applying filters * .acv for video , thanks .

Comment: did you get your answer? because i sorted it out and i can help you !!!

Comment: I still have not found your answer . You can give me a little information was not . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

i used [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)
library and follwing is the command

`String[]
complexCommand={"ffmpeg","-y","-i","file path of input video ","-strict","experimental","-vf","curves=psfile=filter acv file path ","-b","2097k","-vcodec","mpeg4","-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","file path of the output video"}﻿`

for example

```
String[]
complexCommand={"ffmpeg","-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/vk2/in.mp4","-strict","experimental","-vf","curves=psfile=/storage/emulated/0/videokit/sepia.acv","-b","2097k","-vcodec","mpeg4","-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","/storage/emulated/0/videokit/out.mp4"}﻿
```

given link is a forum you may ask your questions regarding ffmepeg there

Comment: Notice all the file paths  should be existed in public folders